# ul and li wont accept to have tags inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm working with bootstrap and i need to align my text into the grids. 
When i do this with tags inside the li it messes up my bullet points.

```
<ul>
   <div class="row"><li> <strong class="col-md-2 col-xs-5 text-left">2015:</strong><p class="col-md-10 col-xs-7 font"> IT-Bachelor - Aarhus Universitet</p></li></div>  
   <div class="row"><li> <strong class="col-md-2 col-xs-5 text-left">2010-2013:</strong><p class="col-md-10 col-xs-7 font"> Højere Handelseksamen (HHX)</p></li></div>
</ul>
```

When load this on my side the bulletpoints are in the left side of the screen, as the picture show.
[bullet point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbQm6.png)

Comment: Only `li` can be a direct child of `ul/ol`, other elements are invalid.

Comment: just to some CSS to override the current behavior

Comment: so if i need to add bootstrap to my text this is impossible?

Comment: Well, do you have to use div:s? Can't you just use li:s instead?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, only  `li` can be a direct child of `ul/ol`, other elements are invalid. As for your situation, I would use it like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5 text-left">
        <p><strong>2015:</strong></p> <!-- added the p to have the same margin -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-7 font">
        <p>IT-Bachelor - Aarhus Universitet</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5 text-left">
        <p><strong>2010-2013:</strong></p> <!-- added the p to have the same margin -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-7 font">
        <p>Højere Handelseksamen (HHX)</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Check the Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/bRXAKTseKa)